# In SugarCRM activities are not appearing in calendar and remainder also not working if we insert call and meeting record through mysql query

Tags: php, sugarcrm

In SugarCRM activities are not appearing in calendar and remainder also not working, if we insert calls and meetings record through mysql query.

I can able to get the reminder in popup and email, if I'm creating calls and meetings from sugarcrm module. But if I fire a mysql query directly then it is not working.

```
INSERT INTO calls(id, name, date_entered, date_modified, modified_user_id, created_by, description, deleted, assigned_user_id, duration_hours, duration_minutes, date_start, date_end, parent_type, status, direction, parent_id, reminder_time, email_reminder_time, email_reminder_sent, outlook_id, repeat_type, repeat_interval, repeat_dow, repeat_until, repeat_count, repeat_parent_id, recurring_source) VALUES ('$id','$subject','$date','$date','$assigned_user_id','$assigned_user_id','$description',0,'$assigned_user_id','$hours','$minutes','$datetime','$datetime','Cases','$status','$direction','$parent_id','$reminder','$reminder','0','','','1','','','','','')
```

Let me know what I'm missing over here.

Finally found the result....

Firing a query to establish relationship between users and calls or meeting (calls_users or meetings_users) will resolve the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would have to see the actual values in the SQL query to really tell.  What I would do is create a call in the UI and then create one using the SQL and compare the two field by field.

That being said, you should never create records via SQL unless you have no other choice.  They should always be created via the bean so support code can run.  I do not think it has anything to do with the problem you are seeing but it is the generally accepted coding practice.

Comment: Even i tried with rest api and bean to save the call record but it is not appearing in calendar